# Array-member comparison in a function not working

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

First of all I'm not even sure whether you call it a member, couldn't think of a better term.

I'm trying to learn basics of debugging and arrays - so I wanted to create something resembling insert-sort from memory (so mistakes would be made) and then debug the program.

```
void findingsmaller (int *array, int num_inputs){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;

    for ( b=1; b == num_inputs-1; b++ ) {
        if ( array[a] > array[b] ) {
            goleft(array, a, b);
            a++;
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say we have this in array: `6 5 3 1 8 7 2 4`. array[a] should be `6` and array[b] should be `5`. `6 > 5` so we should enter the function that would find the first smaller number on the left of the array.

From my debugging session it seems like the condition is `FALSE` so I don't enter `goleft` at all. More specifically, `Step into` ignores it, the testing printf wasn't executed either. I'm assuming the array comparison is not written properly, what's the correction?

[WHOLE CODE](http://pastebin.com/LWQRYPzH) if somebody wants to see other possible mistakes.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: `<= num_inputs` is correct, somehow I thought `for` has `(range1, range2, change)` instead of `(start, condition, change)`. Anyway, now the problem seems that my `goleft` function does its `do-while` cycle one time too many although it shouldn't get past that condition.

EDIT2: A couple of other mistakes were fixed.

1. My printing in `main` is now `for( ; i <= num_inputs-1; )`
2. My `goleft` would do too many iterations due to the condition, fixed into `... while ( a >= 0 && array[a] > array[b] )`
3. My `findingsmaller` would only operate if the number next is smaller but does nothing when the number is greater. For example for `6 8` the program wouldn't function properly. Added `else {a++}`

My fixed [code](http://pastebin.com/Js5ceQ11) for anyone interested in the comparison of the changes.

Comment: did you really mean `b == num_inputs-1`  ? maybe meant `<=` ?

Comment: Yeah, it should, I got confused by strings which have a termination sign at the end.

Comment: FYI: An array normally has entries, elements, etc. _members_ is normally used for `struct` and `union` fields (which are the base for OOP).

Comment: this line: ` for ( b=1; b == num_inputs-1; b++ ) {` has a couple of problems.  1) `b` is already initialized to 1, so the first parameter can be blank.  2) the second parameter is used to stay in the loop.  So unless num_input is 2, this will not work.   Suggest:: `for( ; b < num_inputs; b++ ) {`

Comment: in C, accessing an array starts with 0 and continues through (array size - 1) so setting the second parameter of the `for()` statement to ` b <= num_inputs` will result, for the final loop to be accessing beyond the end of the array.  This results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.   I.E. use the suggested statement in my prior comment

Comment: there are lots of examples of the correct implementation, in C, of the insertion sort algorithm.  Strongly suggest making use of such resources.  Then your efforts can be focused on the problem domain rather trying to 're-invent the wheel' for the insertion sort algorithm

Comment: Thank you all, my program now works. And yes, I had to fix that `num_inputs` in the printing loop too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop is executed as long as the condition is True.

```
for ( ;Condition; )
{
// body
}
```

In your for loop, the condition is always False if the input is greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `b == num_inputs - 1`, you should put `b < num_inputs` in your `for` loop condition. Since the equality isn't true on the first iteration of the loop, it is immediately breaking.

Comment: Ok, this works. Now the problem seems that my `goleft` function does its do-while cyclus one time too many although it shouldn't get past that condition.

Comment: Did you do b <= num_inputs or b < num_inputs? It should be <.

Comment: I changed the whole condition into `while ( a >= 0 && array[a] > array[b] )` aka "it has to be within the array and the left number has to be greater in order to keep going."

Answer (score -1):

I was looking a little bit at your code and i notice something that doesnt work.

```
while (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF)
```

As the documentation of the function scanf say :

> The return value is EOF for an error

your while condition was making you num_imputs reaching 200 even if there was only 3 inputs. I would replace EOF by '\n'.

```
 while (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != '\n') /* stop when the user input '\n' you    
 can replace with any character you want to make it stop. */
```

I did not make a lot of test but this should make your program work fine.

Comment: Error, or in the case of Unix, `CTRL + D`. I wanted to make a program that I could add inputs through `\n` too so that's why I wanted the user to finish his input with EOF.

Comment: Yeah i understand what you want to do, but like i said, you program continue to loop until num_inputs = 200 even if i'm doing a `CTRL + D`

Comment: This is wrong; the return value of `scanf` is the number of inputs successfully read; or `EOF` in case of end-of-file without reading any. The test should be `== 1`

Comment: the `scanf()` function NEVER returns '\n'   It will return the number of successful input/conversion operations or EOF if an error occurs.  The `while()` statement should be checking for `== 1` as any other returned value would be an error.  I.E.  check the returned value, not the parameter value And the %d format specifier will consume '\n' (along with any other white space) and throw it away.

Comment: In this program I didn't check for invalid inputs as the main objective was to work with arrays and learn debugging.